# Using an instance of model in value of checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use an instance of object inside of the `value` tag of a checkbox, this does not seem to work.

My view code:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Purchase", "Upload"))
{
    foreach (var pic in Model) //pic is my class, Picture
    {
        <input type="checkbox" style="float: none" class="bootstrap-checkbox btn.btn-large" value="@pic" name="purchasedItems">
    }

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Purchase(IEnumerable<Picture> purchasedItems)
{

    //My collection is empty here
}
```

If I use `pic.Id` and receive an array of ints instead of collection of Pictures everything works.

Is it a better way to use Id instead of the object itself? Or should I use object and fix my code somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its better to send a List of Ids instead of a List of the object itself, for two main reasons :

1. The less data you pass to the server/shows to the client, the more bandwidth you save .
2. You don't want to get the whole data of the product from the client, i can easily control what you receive using something like a Fiddler and change the price of the product for e.g. so either way you will need to retrieve the product data again from the database using it's Id (for security reasons), so why would you want to pass the whole object data?

Answer (score 1):

You may use form collection to retrieve value from not standard controls :

```
public ActionResult EditProgramTemplateLines(FormCollection formCollection)
{
        for(var i=0; i< chkArrayLength; i++)
        {
           var chkId = formCollection.GetValues(i); // [1,2,3,4]
           ...
        }
}
```

Comment: I get an array of strings instead of array of objects.

Comment: @Anarion It makes sense that you would get a array of strings because you are not really binding anything but looping through the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
foreach (var pic in Model)
    {
        @Html.CheckboxFor(i => pic, new { @class = "bootstrap-checkbox btn.btn-large" });
    }
```

Then let the Controller handle it regularly.

Comment: The part (i => pic) does not work, since pic type is different from the type of the model

Comment: @Anarion What's the difference between the two models?

Comment: The model of the view is List<Picture> and pic is instance of Picture

Comment: @Anarion So the model is `List<Picture>` and the Controller takes in a `IEnumerable<Picture>` ?

Comment: I think i will go with @jony89's answer. Thank you.